# Find coordinates of centroid of an area

Tags: multivariable-calculus, centroid

I would like to find the centroid $(x_c^A,y_c^A)$ of the orange area $A$, marked in the attached picture, i.e. of the area between
$$
f(x)=\ln(x)\qquad\textrm{ and }\qquad g(x)=1, 0\leqslant x\leqslant e.
$$

To this end, I first determined that $A=e-1$, because $B=\int_{1}^e\ln(x)\, dx=1$.

Hence $C=A+B=e$.

Now, the $x$-coordinate $x_c^C$ of the centroid of $C$, which is a rectangle satisfies
$$
x_c^C=\frac{(x_c^A\cdot A)+(x_c^B\cdot B)}{C}=\frac{e}{2}.
$$

Moreover,
$$
x_c^B=\frac{1}{B}\int_1^e x\ln x\, dx=\frac{1}{4}(e^2+1),
$$
so that
$$
x_c^A=\frac{e^2-1}{4(e-1)}.
$$

Equivalently, I get
$$
y_c^A=\frac{1}{e-1}.
$$

Would like to know if I am correct.

[image]

Comment: Rhjg, you wrote that $A$ is the area between 
$$f(x)=\ln(x)\qquad\textrm{ and }\qquad g(x)=1,\;\;0<x\leqslant e.$$Hence, $\;A=e.\;$

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was the orange area bounded also by $y=0$; I corrected my picture and my value of $y_c^A$.

Comment: In this case, if you meant the area bounded also by $y=0$, then it is true that $A=e-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is bounded also by $y=0$ then the $x$-coordinate of the centroid is correct, but the $y$-coordinate is not. A more direct way:
$$|A|=\int_{y=0}^1\int_{x=0}^{e^y}dxdy=[e^y]_0^1=e-1$$
and
$$x_A=\frac{1}{e-1}\int_{y=0}^1\int_{x=0}^{e^y}xdxdy=\frac{[\frac{e^{2y}}{4}]_0^1}{e-1}=\frac{e^{2}-1}{4(e-1)},$$
$$y_A=\frac{1}{e-1}\int_{y=0}^1\int_{x=0}^{e^y}ydxdy=\frac{[e^{y}(y-1)]_0^1}{e-1}=\frac{1}{e-1}.$$

If we consider just the given bounds (without $y=0$) then the domain $A$ is not bounded but it has finite area:
$$|A|=\int_{y=-\infty}^1\int_{x=0}^{e^y}dxdy=[e^y]_{-\infty}^1=e$$
and
$$x_A=\frac{1}{e}\int_{y=-\infty}^1\int_{x=0}^{e^y}xdxdy=\frac{[\frac{e^{2y}}{4}]_{-\infty}^1}{e}=\frac{e}{4},$$
$$y_A=\frac{1}{e}\int_{y=-\infty}^1\int_{x=0}^{e^y}ydxdy=\frac{[e^{y}(y-1)]_{-\infty}^1}{e}=0.$$

Comment: Robert, OP said $A$ is the area between 
$$f(x)=\ln(x)\qquad\textrm{ and }\qquad g(x)=1,\;\;0<x\leqslant e.$$ Consequently, the limits of the first integral should be $y=-\infty$ and $y=1.\;$

Comment: @Angelo Yes, you are correct...